A Standard Way to Position a Barcode with Specified Margins in a Pspicture
Consider the code
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.50in]{geometry}
\usepackage{psvectorian,scalefnt}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent\begin{pspicture}(-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
\psframe[fillcolor=red!75!black,fillstyle=solid](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)%
\psframe[linecolor=red!75!black](-6.985,0)(6.985,21.59)% draws frame.

\rput[bc](0,15.0){\textbf{\textcolor{white}{\scalefont{2.75}{BACK COVER}}}}

%\rput[br](6.42,.37){\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
%% 25pt equals approx. .3472in 
\rput[br](6.07,.72){\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{0-8147-0325-9}{backgroundcolor=FFFFFF borderleft=15 borderright=15 bordertop=14 borderbottom=10 textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

which produces the output:

I have, by trial and error, positioned the barcode so that a 25pt buffer occurs on the bottom and to the right.
QUESTION: Is there a more feasible (direct) way of positioning an ISBN barcode in the lower right-hand corner with 25pt margins to the right and below---regardless of the dimensions of the pspicture?
Thank you.
